# Toggle Edit can't work in looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have form and toggle edit. in this sample it works but when I put in the looping, the toggle dont want to show back become toggle edit when another row click. This is my form.

```js
$('.edit').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings();
  $(trs).each(function() {
    var saveCancel = $(this).children().eq(7).find('.save, .cancel');
    if (saveCancel.length && saveCancel.is(':visible')) {
      saveCancel.hide();
      $(saveCancel).siblings('.edit').show();
    }
  });
  $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});

$('.cancel').click(function() {
  $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
  $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
  $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.save,
.cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .save,
    .cancel {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form method='POST' class="formfield" action='EditCompany'>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='company_name'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='city'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='state'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='zipcode'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='branch'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
          <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='company_name'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='city'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='state'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='zipcode'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='branch'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
          <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='company_name'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='city'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='state'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='zipcode'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='branch'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
          <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

and this is the result in my apps.

[image]

> how to make toggle edit work i  looping?

Comment: I feel its **[toggling here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sj2ps0m5/)** and even in your above snippet. Doesn't seem anything happening like in the screenshot you've shown.. Can you try replicating it?

Comment: Is the 2nd row in your pic dynamically added? If so, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)'s delegate form to capture events that is triggered from dynamically created elements. Like: `$('table').on('click', '.edit', .....);`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : that snippet is simple sample, and the screenshot is result in my apps. I can't explain in the snippet couse need databse for test the looping

Comment: @fuyushimoya can you show me the sample, I am confuse about JS

Comment: You can add static values for testing purpose..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : static? like what?

Comment: See you get data rendered in web page right? Inspect element in browser and copy the whole html there.. Its static data..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao can you see that, http://202.150.158.130:8000/pobox/ username : dicky password: mahardika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Currently, your site has a more basic problem: The `tr`s are all enclosed by a separte `tbody`, which makes your

```
var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings();
```

to get nothing, so their status won't be checked.

Temp fix:

```
var trs =  $(this).closest('tbody').siblings().find('tr')
```

Note that wrap each `tr` with `tbody` may not be what you intend to do. You may either replace the code, or not wrap each `tr` with `tbody`.

When you use `$('.edit').click(...` to register event handler to `.edit`, it'll only bind that handler to all existing `.edit`, which means that `.edit` which are created in the future won't be handle by that event handler.

To solve this, you can instead use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), as I mentioned in comment, the format only need to change a little.

```
//   V Parent to handler dynamically created descendants
$('table').on('click', '.edit', .....);
//               ^        ^  It means we want that `table` to listen to 
//                           all click events from its descendants that have class edit.
```

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
  $('table tr.form:first').eq(0).clone()
    .appendTo($('table tbody'));
  
});

// This will only get to those 
$('table').on('click', '.edit', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings();
  $(trs).each(function() {
    var saveCancel = $(this).children().eq(2).find('.save, .cancel');
    if (saveCancel.length && saveCancel.is(':visible')) {
      saveCancel.hide();
      $(saveCancel).siblings('.edit').show();
    }
  });
  
  $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});

// Your origin form, you can see that it won't work on newly created rows.
$('.edit').click(function() {
  console.log("Static register");
});

$('table').on('click', '.cancel', function() {
  $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
  $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
  $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.save,
.cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add row</button>

<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center' class='form'>
          <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value=''>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='' name='address'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='button' class='edit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Edit'>
            <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'>
            <input type='button' class='cancel' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Cancel'>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: my problem like your sample, when I click row 1, button save and cancel show, and then when I click row 2, in row 1, button save and cancel still showed

Comment: That just a typo that I use `.eq(3)` to get that `.save, .cancel`, and it should be `.eq(2)`, as I deleted some useless input column, now it should work as expect.

Comment: I dont know why in my apps, the button save and cancel still showed

Comment: I've inspect your page, each of your `tr` is enclose by an `tbody`, so `var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings();` won't get anything, that's the problem.

Comment: can you see that, 202.150.158.130:8000/pobox username : dicky password: mahardika . and please correction

Comment: Added the cause and solution to top of my answer.

Comment: where I put ' $(this).closest('tbody').siblings().find('tr'); ' ? for fix it?

Comment: thank you for your help, I try to delete tbody and it works

Comment: hey buddy, are you still online?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96515/discussion-between-fuyushimoya-and-dicky-mahardika).